# Spring Boot ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

In my Spring Boot 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT application in order to fix the ActiveMQ security problem with:

```
This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

I have to add following parameter(I'd like to allow all classes)

```
-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"
```

to application VM arguments.

Is it possible to supply this parameter via application.properties or some other way inside of my Spring Boot application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set in in the spring boot application. In the configuration class, you would need to get a handle on the ActiveMQConnectionFactory and set these, like this:

```
@Inject
private ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

private void addTrustedPackage(){
     final List<String> trustedPackageList = new ArrayList<>(connectionFactory.getTrustedPackages());
     trustedPackageList.add("the packages that you want to add");
     connectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(trustedPackageList);
}
```

The reason you need to get the list of existing packages and add to it is because it contains base packages like java.lang, etc.

You can also set these in application.properties file using

```
spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=false # Trust all packages.
spring.activemq.packages.trusted= # Comma-separated list of specific packages to trust (when not trusting all packages).
```

REFERENCE: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=true` to trust all packages, or `spring.activemq.packages.trusted=com.example.foo,com.example.bar` if you want more control.